# Change Default Compiler Within Emacs?

Tags: c, gcc, emacs, makefile, clang

I use `M-x compile` within Emacs to compile my C code which then initiates `make -k` and allows me to compile the code. I wish to use Clang (or conceivably GCC 4.8 after I install it) as the default compiler. I have `cc` aliased to `clang -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -ggdb -O0` and while this invokes `Clang` from the command line outside of Emacs, invoking `M-x compile` from within Emacs still seems to alias `cc` to GCC version 4.7 which is what I have installed. I wish to tap into the richer and more understandable error and warning messages provided by Clang (and GCC 4.8) but do not wish to create a separate makefile for every short student-level program I am writing, since I am currently going through K&R including solving the exercises.

How do I convince Emacs that `M-x compile` and `make -k` should invoke Clang (or GCC 4.8) instead of the older version of GCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a makefile, and explicitly use clang on the compilation line.

Something like this would work:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS= -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -ggdb -O0

%: %.c
	$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Note that the last line needs to begin with a tab in order to actually work.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't emacs, it's make. It defaults to using the environment variable CC, which in turn defaults to gcc. Just run this before you start emacs (assuming you're using Unix):

```
$ export CC=clang
```

Alternatively, use a makefile that specifies CC directly.

Comment: I don't have it set as an environmental variable but I do have `cc` (small letters) aliased within my shell to `clang` with the above listed options, and do have that line set in both my `.profile` and `.bashrc` files. Typing cc from the command line correctly starts `clang` instead of `gcc`. Should I export it as an `env` variable instead? And if yes, presumably, use the `env` variable convention of ALL CAPS?

Comment: @haziz - yes, the capitals are essential

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your makefile, you are using `$(CC)` to compile your code, you can do one of the following:

- When you do `M-x compile`, you can change the compile command to `CC=clang make -k`.
- Add the following line in your `.emacs` file:

  `(setq compile-command "CC=clang make -k")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without `make`. @Lazylabs mentioned that you can change the value of `compile-command`. To make it mode-specific, add this to your Emacs config:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq compile-command 
              (concat "clang -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -ggdb -O0" buffer-file-name))))
```

It will use current file name by default.